# dlopen wait's on futex call

Tags: dlopen

I try to load `libmysqlcppconn.so` with dlopen but the program waits on the call to this function.

Strace shows me:

```
futex(0x7faff79b3e00, FUTEX_WAIT, 12122,
```

Strace of pid 12122 shows:

```
futex(0xaadffae3eee, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2,
```

But when I staticaly linked my code with `libmysqlcppconn.so` in NetBeans it works fine.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

> when I staticaly linked my code with libmysqlcppconn.so in NetBeans it works fine

Since it is impossible to statically link `libmysqlcppconn.so`, you *didn't* do that. Probably you statically linked `libmysqlcppconn.a`.

> What is going on?

You have not provided enough info to answer that. Attach to your hanging process with `gdb`, execute `thread apply all where`, and update your question with that info. *Then* someone may be able to tell you what's going on.